# Is there a concise way to match a specific capital letter (and a varied number of spaces before and between the characters) exactly three times

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match a particular character three times. There will be spaces between the character. The catch is that I don't know the character I need to match beforehand.

For example:

```
   D       D                D     Would be a match
   D       D                B     Would not be a match (because of the B)
   A        A             A       Would be a match
   D       D      j        D      Would not be a match (because of the j)
```

My thought was that I could let the first match determine the second and third match but I did not know how to accomplish this.

[Regex101 - matching three Bs](https://regex101.com/r/ctldnC/1)

```
(?:\s*)([B]){1}(?:\s*)([\1])(?:\s*)([\1]){1}
```

Ultimately I want to use the regular expression in an R program.

Comment: something like `/D\s+D\s+D/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could match 1+ times a tab or space using a character class and a single capturing group with a [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) `\1` without using it in a character class.

```
\b([A-Z])[ \t]+\1[ \t]+\1\b
```

- `\b` Word boundary
- `([A-Z])` Capture **group 1** Match an uppercase char A-Z
- `[ \t]+\1` Match 1+ times a space or tab and a backreference to group 1
- `[ \t]+\1` Same as above
- `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SkoUwG/1)

You could also use `\s` instead of a space or tab but can also match a newline

Comment: so the trick is to only match the first on then refer to it the second and third time. Thanks

Comment: @Mutuelinvestor Yes and using `\1` in a character class `[\1]` is not a valid backreference.